# Parsing Jetty log records

Tags: java, regex, parsing, logging

For the given input example:

```
70.80.110.200 -  -  [12/Apr/2011:05:47:34 +0000] "GET /notify/click?r=http://www.xxxxxx.com/hello_world&rt=1302587231462&iid=00000 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; HotbarSearchToolbar 1.1; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; AskTbFWV5/5.11.3.15590)" 4 4
```

I would like to define the following parsing logic (probably regex)

1. Extract the IP (3 digits, dot) * 4 =>
   70.80.110.200
2. Extract the date =>
   12/Apr/2011
3. Extract the time =>
   05:47:34
4. Extract the URI (starts with \" and ends with \"). =>
   /notify/click?r=http://www.xxxxxx.com/hello_world&rt=1302587231462&iid=00000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code sample (based on [hsz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729339/parsing-jetty-log-records/5729460#5729460)):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexDemo {

  public static void main( String[] argv ) {
    String pat = "^([0-9.]*).*?\\[(\\d+\\/\\w+\\/\\d+):(\\d+:\\d+:\\d+).*?\\].*?(\\/[^ ]*).*$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
    String target = "70.80.110.200 -  -  [12/Apr/2011:05:47:34 +0000] \"GET /notify/click?r=http://www.xxxxxx.com/hello_world&rt=1302587231462&iid=00000 HTTP/1.1\" 302 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; HotbarSearchToolbar 1.1; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; AskTbFWV5/5.11.3.15590)\" 4 4";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(target);
    System.out.println("pattern: " + pat);
    System.out.println("target: " + target);

    if (m.matches()) {
      System.out.println("found");
      for (int i=0; i <= m.groupCount(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
/^([0-9.]+).*?\[(\d+\/\w+\/\d+):(\d+:\d+:\d+).*?\].*?(\/[^ ]*).*$/
```

As you expect, in following groups (1, 2, 3, 4) you will get all data you specified - for example `.group(3)` is time.

Comment: Sorry but no - use google/book to find how to use regexp in Java.

Comment: Not 100% correct - fixed version: r = /^([0-9.]*).*?\[(\d+\/\w+\/\d+):(\d+:\d+:\d+).*?\].*?(\/[^ ]*).*$/
(the original version is matching just one digit/full stop instead of the whole group, and it doesnt' escape the square brackets)

Comment: @Frank Schmitt - I've fixed it 23 minutes ago. ;)

Comment: @hsz, but does he LEARN anything from this?

Comment: I provided him a regexp that he expected. Sory but I'm too lazy to do homework for lazy people.

Comment: @hsz: I'm not asking because I don't how about Matcher, Patten and String.split()... it's just that this code did not work for me and I've tried to politely imply that it's would perhaps be beneficial to fix the issues and quicker to communicate if an example was provided. I thank you for the regex, I did not know that Matcher has group(n) option...

Comment: @Maxim Veksler: Ok, my bad - I was a bit rough. However below my answer, Frank Schmitt posted some usage of my regex. Have a nice day !

Comment: @hsz One question regarding SO netiquette: Is it ok to post an answer based on someone else's answer (as I did)? Or is it considered rude?

Comment: @Frank Schmitt I don't know - I think, it's ok when you notice base author as you did.

Comment: @Frank, you can always make the reference into an actual link

Answer (score 2):

Ensure Jetty is configured to do NSCA-compatible logging, then you can use any NCSA log analyzer to analyze the logs.

If you want to do it by hand, then this is a nice usecase for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
String s = "70.80.110.200 -  -  [12/Apr/2011:05:47:34 +0000] \"GET /notify/click?r=http://www.xxxxxx.com/hello_world&rt=1302587231462&iid=00000 HTTP/1.1\" 302 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; HotbarSearchToolbar 1.1; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; AskTbFWV5/5.11.3.15590)\" 4 4";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}).*?\\" + //ip
                            "[([^:]*):"+ //date
                            "(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*?\\].*?"+ //time
                            "(/[^\\s]*).*$"); //uri

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find()){
    String ip = m.group(1);
    String date = m.group(2);
    String time = m.group(3);
    String uri = m.group(4);
}
```